# Evaluate: $\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\log(1-x) \tan(x)}{1-x\tan^2(x)} \ dx$

Tags: integration

$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\log(1-x) \tan(x)}{1-x\tan^2(x)} \ dx\tag1$$

What hints do I used to change this integral into a more manageable to work on?

Comment: this does not have a closed form

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where you did catch this monster and I should be very surpised to see a closed form solution.

Beside numerical integration, series expansion of the integrand would be a way
$$\frac{\log(1-x) \tan(x)}{1-x\tan^2(x)}=-x^2-\frac{x^3}{2}-\frac{2 x^4}{3}-\frac{17 x^5}{12}-\frac{17 x^6}{18}-\frac{33
   x^7}{20}-\frac{2593 x^8}{1260}+O\left(x^{9}\right)$$ but, as shown below for an expansion to $O\left(x^{n}\right)$, the resulting integral $I_n$ would converge very slowly
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & I_n \\
 10 & -0.422168 \\
 20 & -0.516181 \\
 30 & -0.548704 \\
 40 & -0.561920 \\
 50 & -0.567757 \\
 60 & -0.570465 \\
 70 & -0.571763 \\
 80 & -0.572401 \\
 90 & -0.572719 \\
 100 & -0.572881
\end{array}
\right)$$ while numerical integration would lead to $-0.573053$.